# Return different content based on multiple select inputs

Tags: javascript, php, select, advanced-custom-fields

So basically I am trying to show different prices based on multiple select inputs. The prices are stored in WordPress using Advance custom fields but thats just a detail really, unless it can be done with AFC.

```
<select>
 <option>12 months</option>
 <option>24 months</option>
 <option>36 months</option>
</select>

<select>
 <option>1000 deposit</option>
 <option>2000 deposit</option>
 <option>3000 deposit</option>
</select>

* if 12 months and 2000 deposit are selected Show a dynamic price and so on *
```

What would be the best way to do this? I have seen many examples of a single select inputs but not various inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using JavaScript by adding event listeners to each select element and then calling a function to calculate output based on user selection. In the example below I simply display the result in an input element. The code would look something like this.

```js
let select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
//add eventListener to call calculation function on change of first select
select1.addEventListener("change", () => {
 calculate( select1.value, document.getElementById("select2").value );
});

let select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
//add eventListener to call calculation function on change of second select
document.getElementById("select2").addEventListener("change", () => {
 calculate( document.getElementById("select1").value, select2.value );
});

   

//calculate result and display it in an input box
function calculate( val1, val2 ){
 //possibility 1
  if ( parseInt( val1 ) === 12 && parseInt( val2 ) === 1000 ) {
   //assign some value to something you want
 document.getElementById("result").value = "$150.25";
  } else if ( parseInt( val1 ) === 12 && parseInt( val2 ) === 2000 ) {
   document.getElementById("result").value = "$50.25";
  } else if ( parseInt( val1 ) === 12 && parseInt( val2 ) === 3000 ) {
   document.getElementById("result").value = "$10.25";
  }
  //.......and so on with the rest of possibilities
}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
 <option value="12">12 months</option>
 <option value="24">24 months</option>
 <option value="36">36 months</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
 <option value="1000">1000 deposit</option>
 <option value="2000">2000 deposit</option>
 <option value="3000">3000 deposit</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="result">
```

Probably not the most elegant way of doing it, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Similar to what I need. What I actually need is for when two conditions are true. For example if they choose 12 months & then 2000 deposit then it displays a value of my choosing... say I want it to display £230.75... how would I do that for say 10 different pre-determined prices?

Comment: If I understood you correctly then you could achieve this by setting a lot of if conditions or switches to assign a specific value based on user selection. So for example if ( val1 === 2000 && val2 === 12 ) { //set the value here }

Comment: That sounds great but trying to replicate your solution on my site ai am getting this console error and the input doesn't populate, thanks again

selects.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at selects.js:3
(anonymous) @ selects.js:3

Comment: It seems that the select you're trying to add event listener to either does exist at the time you try to add it or perhaps you misstyped something. It's difficult to diagnose the exact problem without knowing how you're trying to do things. Are you adding JavaScript through a WordPress plugin or theme or some other way ?

Comment: I have created a new js file in my js folder, referenced it my head and put the selects in my homepage template, i will attach some images in a reply... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Links below.... this is the only way i could show images because I am new, I hope this is ok?

```
https://ibb.co/mSYyzf
https://ibb.co/bRT95L
https://ibb.co/ds72QL
https://ibb.co/nGAdzf
```

Comment: It seems that your script might be running before markup is created. You could try wrapping the code that references markup to fire only after scripts have and page have completely loaded. The two variables containing select as well as addEventListener code should be put inside document.window.onload = function() { //code goes here }. This should ensure that your html code is available to be grabbed by JavaScript.

Comment: @BambiOurLord Just one more thing. I am struggling using switch and if else statemtents to work with 2 selects...

If i have 4 set prices....say £110, £120, £130, £150....

if i choose option 1 from the first select and option 3 from the second i want to display £130 and so on... I have custom fields set with the values i need in the backend of wordpress i just need the logic as i can't work it out. I will just set up as many variations as i need. thank you :)

Comment: A bit late to reply because of sleep. To make that happen inside that calculation function you would have to check both values that you're passing to it and based on that give a result. So it might look something like this if ( val1 === 12 && val2 === 2000 ) { //set the price here for output } and then add as many options as you need. Values coming from select may be strings so you might have to coerce them to be integers using val1.toInt before comparing or inside if statement have numbers wrapped in double quotes. Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if I were of help, good luck!

Comment: My bad I meant parseInt( val1 ); if you want to change its data type during comparison.

Comment: @BambiOurLord you have been a massive heml, if you could please show me and example that would be excellent. I have trouble understanding if i dont see examples visually. many thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how it can be done. Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it has helped as it also helps me. Thank you :)